How do I make the content in a Flutter TableRow same height?
I have created a flutter table that has 3 column. The second column consist of a row of two containers and I want to make the container to have the same height as the row.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const TableExampleApp());

class TableExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Table Sample')),
        body: const TableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(),
      columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
        0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        2: FixedColumnWidth(64),
      },
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      children: [
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Data 1"),
            ),
             TableCell(
              verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text("Data 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Data 3"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I have tried wrapping the containers with Expandable and Flexible widgets but still no results
Got:
enter image description here
Expected:
enter image description here

Before:

After:

Just like with all Rows, if  you want them to expand, you need to set the crossAxisAlignment: to .stretch (by default it's set to .center):
TableCell(
              verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
              child: Row(
                // Add the below line to stretch the children
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, 
                children: [
                  Flexible(


Using your code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const TableExampleApp());

class TableExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Table Sample')),
        body: const TableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(),
      columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
        0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        2: FixedColumnWidth(64),
      },
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      children: [
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Data 1"),
            ),
            TableCell(
              verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                    .stretch, // <--- Add this line to stretch the children
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text("Data 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Data 3"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

